# How does respecifying a inherited virtual method allow it to disambiguate correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was doing some fun stuff with googlemock and decided to split my classes into pure virtual classes and concrete implementations to avoid needing to special casing for my mocks. However, the compiler started complaining that:

```
error: undefined reference to 'vtable for <ConcreteClass>'
```

I managed to reproduce the issue with the following:

simple.h:

```
namespace simple {

class InterfaceA {
 public:
  virtual ~InterfaceA() {}

  virtual int MethodOne() const = 0;
};

class InterfaceB : public InterfaceA {
 public:
  ~InterfaceB() override {}

  virtual int MethodTwo() const = 0;
};

class ImplA : public InterfaceA {
 public:
  ImplA(int to_return);
  ~ImplA() override {}

  int MethodOne() const override;

 private:
  int to_return_;
};

class ImplB : public InterfaceB, public ImplA {
 public:
  ImplB();
  ~ImplB() override {}

  // int MethodOne() const override;
  int MethodTwo() const override;
};
}  // namespace simple
```

simple.cc

```
#include "simple.h"

namespace simple {

ImplA::ImplA(int to_return) : to_return_(to_return) {}
int ImplA::MethodOne() const { return to_return_; }

ImplB::ImplB() : ImplA(5) {}
// int ImplB::MethodOne() const { return ImplA::MethodOne(); }
int ImplB::MethodTwo() const { return 2; }
}  // namespace simple
```

The issue was the bits I have commented out; once I added those things into the files, the compiler and my tests were happy. So intuitively this makes sense, as now there are concrete methods defined for the virtual ones, and the compiler previously doesn't/can't guess which super class methods I wanted.

My question is twofold:

1. How does the specification of `ImplA::MethodOne()` allow it to be called as it isn't a static variable?
2. Is there an implicit `ImplA` pointer somewhere in the `ImplB` object at creation time that allows it to call a method on `ImplA` despite not being a static method?

Comment: You somewhere missed to specify a virtual destructor may be? Can you at least link to a [MCVE] at an online compiler like [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c61c11fdd491ee1f) (there's nothing special happening from my try).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you can see in the example that all destructors are specified. The problem is the commented out code staying commented out. Once you uncomment them, it will compile fine.

Comment: lookup multiple inheritance diamond problem and you'll find the answers you are after..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have diamond-shape inheritance, so you need to specify the virtual keyword when inhering from InterfaceA. See the code [here](http://ideone.com/QVddjj)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace simple {

class InterfaceA {
 public:
  virtual ~InterfaceA() {}

  virtual int MethodOne() const = 0;
};

class InterfaceB : virtual public InterfaceA {  // <-- note the virtual keyword
 public:
  ~InterfaceB() override {}

  virtual int MethodTwo() const = 0;
};

class ImplA : virtual public InterfaceA { // <-- note the virtual keyword
 public:
  ImplA(int to_return);
  ~ImplA() override {}

  int MethodOne() const override;

 private:
  int to_return_;
};

class ImplB : public InterfaceB, public ImplA {
 public:
  ImplB();
  ~ImplB() override {}

  //int MethodOne() const override;
  int MethodTwo() const override;
};

ImplA::ImplA(int to_return) : to_return_(to_return) {}
int ImplA::MethodOne() const { return to_return_; }

ImplB::ImplB() : ImplA(5) {}
// int ImplB::MethodOne() const { return ImplA::MethodOne(); }
int ImplB::MethodTwo() const { return 2; }
}  // namespace simple


int main() {
    simple::ImplA implA(100);
    cout << implA.MethodOne() << endl << endl;

    simple::ImplB implB;
    cout << implB.MethodOne() << endl;
    cout << implB.MethodTwo() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

BTW, you wrote about a static method in your questions... There is not static method there and when you call `ImplA::MethodOne()`, you, in fact, call `this->ImplA::MethodOne()`. So, the call IS tied to an object which is `this`.

Comment: Hmm... I've read some things about how virtual inheritance can be bad so my design is probably is in need of rethinking regardless... This alternative works though so, accepting it.

Comment: As a simple redesign change, I would suggest modifying InterfaceB class by removing its inheritance, since it is completely independent of InterfaceA. (Note that you have to modify the destructor of InterfaceB, too). see this [link](http://ideone.com/7bI82B)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImplB` class has 2 `InterfaceA`s in it's inheritance tree. You need to use virtual inheritance (cf. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance).